# How to use functions in c++?

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I am supposed to get the following code to display something along the lines of: "The sum of 1 to 10 is 55." (The larger number can be any number that was just the example I got.) I was given this code to use.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Compute the sum of all of the numbers from 1 to n where n
// is a natural number
// use the formula: n(n+1)/2
void compute_sum(int limit) // compute_sum function
{
int sum_to_limit;
sum_to_limit = limit * (limit + 1) / 2;
}
int main()
{
int sum = 0;
int maxNumber;
// get the maxNumber for the function call
cout << "Enter a whole number greater than 0" << endl;
cin >> maxNumber;
// call compute sum
compute_sum(maxNumber); // Call to compute_sum function
// display the sum calculated by the compute_sum function
cout << "The sum of 1 to " << maxNumber;
cout << " is " << sum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I do not understand how funcctions work at all and do not have any idea how I would go about getting this to work. The only thing I know about this (and this is from the teacher) is that the change required is not major. "Note: If you are making major changes to the main and compute_sum funtions you are probably
doing way too much work." I have tried changing the function to an int function with a return but I could not get it to work properly (most likely due to not knowing how functions work). So can someone please help me?

Comment: This might help: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm

Comment: You say you tried an "int function". What you mean is that the function should *return* an `int`. This should be the way to go. Can you post your changed code you tried?

Comment: `int variable = functionthatreturnsint(whatever);`?

Comment: You need to make `compute_sum` return the value it computes.

Comment: If you are learning from a human instructor, you will need to talk with the instructor.  Understanding writing and using functions is a prerequisite to this assignment. **If you do not understand the requirements, talk with the person who created the requirements before starting.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you're missing is the return type of the function, and then to actually return that value from the function.

At the moment you have

```
void compute_sum(int limit) // compute_sum function
{
    int sum_to_limit;
    sum_to_limit = limit * (limit + 1) / 2;
}
```

A function prototype in C looks pretty much like this

```
<return type> <name> (<parameters>)
{
    // your logic here

    return <your_own_variable> // Note: You can omit this if the return type is void (it means the function doesn't return anything)
}
```

You want to modify your function so you are returning the integer value you're calculating inside of it

```
int compute_sum(int limit) // compute_sum function
{
    int sum_to_limit;
    sum_to_limit = limit * (limit + 1) / 2;
    return sum_to_limit;
}
```

So what happens is after main runs, when the the point of execution hits

```
compute_sum(maxNumber);
```

The program flow jumps to that function and executes the code inside of it. When the function finishes, it returns the value back to where it was originally called from. So you also need to add this to store the value returned

```
int result = compute_sum(maxNumber);
```

and then make sure to output that value to the user.

You can also make the `computer_sum` function a little more terse my not storing a temporary variable, you can just do this

```
int compute_sum(int limit) // compute_sum function
{
    return limit * (limit + 1) / 2;
}
```

I hope that helps. There's a lot more going on behind the scenes but that's the basic idea. Good luck! :)

Comment: I changed it to have an int instead of void and to to return sum_to_limit in the function but I am not sure where to put the result = compute_sum(maxNumber) does that go after compute_sum(maxNumber?

Comment: You should replace `compute_sum(maxNumber)` with the line `int result = compute_sum(maxNumber)`. You need the new int variable to store the result of the function. You can then call `cout << "The sum of 1 to " << result;` That should work

Comment: Thank you so much I know this was really a question I should already know but this was very helpful and I don't mean to use this as a quick answer to homework I genuinely don't know how to use functions that much.

Comment: No problem! Functions are invaluable. I hope the explanation helped